# How to prevent to insert duplicate value in sqlite database (if duplicate then overwrite)

Tags: android, sqlite

I had created two table in my database, In both table I am inserting value at the same time, now what I want to do is that, I want to insert record in second table, but the condition is that, if there is two same record then I want insert only one record not duplicate value, In second table there is two field one is **id** and second is **category**, when user insert two same category that time I want to insert only one entry, below is my code which is not working properly, It insert all record accept duplicate value..

```
public long InsertCat(String idd, String cat) 
  { 
     try 
       {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        long rows = 0;
        db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
        ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
        Val.put("IDD", idd); 
        Val.put("Category", cat);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CATEGER + " WHERE Category='"+cat+"'",null);
        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            if(c.getString(0).equals(cat))
            {
                flag=true;
            }
        }           
        if(flag==true)
        {
          rows=db.update(TABLE_CATEGER, Val, "Category='"+cat+"'"  , null);     
          System.out.print(rows);
          db.close();
        }
        if(flag==false)
        {
            rows = db.insert(TABLE_CATEGER, null, Val);
            System.out.print(rows);             
            db.close();
        }
        return rows; // return rows inserted.
         } catch (Exception e) {
         return -1;
         }
        }
```

Comment: define primary key to the column you want to make unique..then it will not have duplicate values...

Comment: but i want update that record if it is duplicate..

Comment: or i can say if it is duplicate then overwrite

Comment: `$add    = query("INSERT INTO stocks (id , symbol , shares) VALUES(? ,? ,? )ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE shares = shares + VALUES(shares)",$_SESSION["id"],strtoupper($_POST["symbol"]),$_POST["shares"]);` this is a simple MySQL query might be helpful to you.

Comment: read my code and explain with code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put all your values inside `ContentValues` and then call this on `writableDatabase`

```
db.insertWithOnConflict(tableName, null, contentValues,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

**EDIT:**

Well all you need is only this part of code

```
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    long rows = 0;
    db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
    ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
    Val.put("IDD", idd); 
    Val.put("Category", cat);
    rows = db.insertWithOnConflict(tableName, null, contentValues,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

`insertWithOnConflict` methods follows the last parameter as the reaction algorithm when an duplicate row is Found. And for a duplicate row to be found, the primary keys has to clash. If all this satisfys the row would surely get Replaced :-/ If not something else is going wrong..

Comment: does your table has a primary key col??

Comment: db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CATEGER +"(IDD INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +" Category TEXT(100));");

Comment: can i make Category  column as a primary key

Comment: Well, i suggest you use my code only if u dont have a `auto increment` col as primary key and also nothing is `dependent` on the `auto increment col`. To know wats the problem, i suggest you figure it out urself, itll take quite a research to find it :-/

Answer (score 3):

While creating your table, put constraint on your column(Primary key or Unique key).This will not only the duplicate value to be inserted into your database.

Answer (score 0):

Check with the primary key of which you want assign then while inserting check with on duplicate key..
if you want you update the row

> on duplicate key update

As mentioned i am writing the code on duplicate key

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO TABLE_CATEGER(value1,value2,value3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table_name (idColoumn, categoryColumn) VALUES (?, ?)
```

It will add new row if it does not exist or update row if it exists.
hope this will help you.

Comment: Not working, I have used the same query but its inserting duplicate data

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me,and i also created Category as a primary key..

```
ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
Val.put("IDD", idd); 
Val.put("Category", cat);
long rows=db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_CATEGER, null,  Val,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
System.out.print(rows);
Log.d("kkkkkkkkkk",""+ rows);
db.close();
return rows; // return rows inserted.
```

Answer (score 0):

use insertWithOnConflict() method instead of insert()

```
response = sqLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_TRACKER_LOGS_LINES, null, contentValues,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```