# Avoiding duplicates, SQLITE, android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a button, when user clicks it it passes some value and im adding this value with cv.put("name", name), how can i avoid adding duplicates?

Comment: check where not exist command on sql it might help. or you can simply inner join your own table and check if it does exist or not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26326817/3998402 solves your problem

Comment: On SO, either [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer, or write your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it`s better to do it in your database structure
in your

```
 SQLiteOpenHelper

 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+MyDatabaseColums.USERINFOEntry.TABLE_NAME+" ("
                + MyDatabaseColums.USERINFOEntry.U_id+ " INTEGER , "
                + MyDatabaseColums.USERINFOEntry.mrname+ " TEXT, "
                + MyDatabaseColums.USERINFOEntry.meEmail+ " TEXT, "
"UNIQUE ( " +YOUR_id+") ON CONFLICT IGNORE"+");";
```

this will ignore any conflict in your Field

or use

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+MyDatabaseColums.USERINFOEntry.TABLE_NAME+" ("
                + MyDatabaseColums.USERINFOEntry.U_id+ " INTEGER , "
                + MyDatabaseColums.USERINFOEntry.mrname+ " TEXT, "
                + MyDatabaseColums.USERINFOEntry.meEmail+ " TEXT, "
"UNIQUE ( " +YOUR_id+") ON CONFLICT REPLACE"+");";
```

to replace when conflict in Field

Answer (score 1):

1- Make sure you have some appropriate constraint in your table, such as PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE.

2-When inserting, add a value to this constrained column via ContentValues. If inserting the new row would violate some constraint, the conflicting rows are first deleted and then the new row is inserted.

```
ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
Val.put("IDD", id); 
Val.put("Category", cat);
long rows=db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_CATEGER, null,  Val,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
System.out.print(rows);
db.close(); 
Log.d(TAG,""+ rows);
```

Gordon Linoff answer shows you how to make some columns UNIQUE

Answer (score 0):

I you have a table t and you do not want duplicate values of `name`, then the best method is to have the database maintain the integrity of the data.

SQL offers unique indexes/constraints just for this purpose.  For instance, you can create a unique index on the data:

```
create unique index unq_t_name on t(name);
```

Any attempt to create a duplicate `name` value in `t` (whether by `insert` or `update`) will generate an error.