# android - prevent duplicate insert data in SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I just learned to use sqlite on android. how to prevent duplicate data when it will be inserted .. so, when there is same data entry, it will overwrite the data?

here I attach the code snippet:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_FAVORIT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Constant.favoritDBtable + "("
                + Constant.id_postFav + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + Constant.titleFav + " TEXT," + Constant.namaPerusahaanFav + " TEXT,"
                + Constant.lokasiFav + " TEXT," + Constant.kriteria_1Fav + " TEXT," + Constant.kriteria_2Fav
                + " TEXT," + Constant.kriteria_3Fav + " TEXT," + Constant.gajiFav + " TEXT," + Constant.img_logoFav
                + " TEXT," + Constant.tanggalFav + " TEXT);";

public String addFavorit(Favorit favorit){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
//        long rows = 0;

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Constant.titleFav, favorit.getTitleFav());
        values.put(Constant.namaPerusahaanFav, favorit.getNamaPerusahaanFav());
        values.put(Constant.lokasiFav, favorit.getLokasiFav());
        values.put(Constant.kriteria_1Fav, favorit.getKriteria_1Fav());
        values.put(Constant.kriteria_2Fav, favorit.getKriteria_2Fav());
        values.put(Constant.kriteria_3Fav, favorit.getKriteria_3Fav());
        values.put(Constant.gajiFav, favorit.getGajiFav());
        values.put(Constant.img_logoFav, favorit.getImg_logoFav());
        values.put(Constant.tanggalFav, favorit.getTanggalFav());

      db.insert(Constant.favoritDBtable, null, values,);

Log.d("Favorit saved: ", "Success 200 OK");
        return null;
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (job.getTitle() != null && job.getLokasi() != null){
        saveToFavoritDB();
        }
    }

    private void saveToFavoritDB() {
        Favorit favorit = new Favorit();

        favorit.setTitleFav(job.getTitle());
        favorit.setGajiFav(job.getGaji());

        Log.d(TAG, "gaji " + job.getGaji());

        db.addFavorit(favorit);

        List<Favorit> favList = db.getAllFavorit();

        for (Favorit each : favList) {
            String log = "ID: " + each.getTitleFav() + ", Name: " + each.getLokasiFav() + ", Phone: " + each.getGajiFav();
            Log.d(TAG, "saveToFavoritDB: " + String.valueOf(db.getCountFavorit()));
            Log.d(TAG, "Hasil: " + log);
        }
    }
```

hope you can help me

Comment: how do you determine that the data is duplicate?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326696/how-to-prevent-to-insert-duplicate-value-in-sqlite-databse-if-duplicate-then-ov

Comment: when the same data goes into the favorite list. @VladMatvienko

Comment: how do you check that the data is the same? What would the `if` condition be?

Comment: I have tried it, but the incoming data is still duplicate @JohnJoe

Comment: I tried to insert an object into my favorites list, when I double-clicked the object to put it into the favorite list and I checked the object duplicate but ID_FAVLIST continued to grow @VladMatvienko

Comment: that is not what I asked.

Comment: after I see another post thread, some use if condition & some are using insertWithOnConflict. which is the best and can I apply? @VladMatvienko

Comment: You still didn't answer my question.

Comment: You should check whether the data is already exists in SQLite. If exists then   it will not insert, otherwise insert.

Comment: no, i have not checked it with if condition or otherwise @VladMatvienko

Comment: how the right conditions so I can check it? Is it like this:
if (favorites == 0) {
db.insert () } else {
TOAST
}
@JohnJoe

Comment: @MuhammadImanudin check my answer

Comment: OK i will check it @JohnJoe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before go through `addFavorit` method, you can add one method to check whether the data is already exists to prevent duplicate.

```
  boolean check;

  check = checkDuplicate(...,...,...,id_post); // check whether data exists
    if(check == true)  // if exists
    {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Data Already Exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        db.addFavorit(favorit);
  }

  public static boolean checkDuplicate(String TableName,String dbfield, String fieldValue, int id_post) {
  String Query = ".... WHERE "+ Constant.id_postFav +"="+ id_post; // your query 
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
      if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
      cursor.close();
      return false;
     }
      cursor.close();
      return true;
  }
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much friends. this work, but there are little constraints. I have created a unique ID (primary key) in sqlite (id_favList) and took id_post other data on JSON. when I fill the fieldValue with getId_post from JSON and then when to enter to favList, the data is defined as "Data already exists". how to make the comparison is by comparing id_post. if id_post (from json) has been in sqlite then "Data already exists", if id_post is not there then i will add it into db.

Comment: you mean `id_post` is same with `id_favList`?

Comment: no, id_favlist it for sqlite with autoincrement key primary key. However, on this id_post I took from JSON

Comment: so that determines whether or not I want id_post that I take from the json

Comment: does this sort of query its true?

String Query = "SELECT * FROM " + Constant.favoritDBtable; // your query

Comment: Let me clarify on thing. Are you want to compare `id_favList`(in sqlite) and `getId_post` from `JSON` ? If the id from `JSON` is same as the id in `sqlite`, it will not insert ?

Comment: sorry not as you mean, i want to compare if id_post (from JSON) already exist, so it will not insert @John Joe

Comment: or how do you think the best way to compare it? @John Joe

Comment: how to know whether id_post is already exists in SQLite ? Can you provide some example/ data in your sqlite ?

Comment: here I attach the sqlite structure that I created

String CREATE_FAVORIT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Constant.favoritDBtable + "("
                + Constant.id_favList + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + Constant.titleFav + " TEXT," + Constant.namaPerusahaanFav + " TEXT,"
                + Constant.lokasiFav + " TEXT," + Constant.kriteria_1Fav + " TEXT," + Constant.kriteria_2Fav
                + " TEXT," + Constant.kriteria_3Fav + " TEXT," + Constant.gajiFav + " TEXT," + Constant.img_logoFav
                + " TEXT," + Constant.tanggalFav + " TEXT);";

Comment: sorry i reply this for too long @John Joe

Comment: you have  an id in sqlite called `id_favList`, then you want to get  `id_post (from JSON)` and check whether `id_post` is already exists in SQLite by comparing `id_favList` and `id_post` ?

Comment: Yeah like that.
I will compare it only with id_post (from Json) only @John Joe

Comment: if so, do I have to create a new field to hold and compare id_post (from JSON)? @John Joe

Comment: no. You should retrieve the `id_favList` and compare with `id_post`

Comment: Ok.
how to compare it?
I have tried using insertWithOnConflict but have not succeeded

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Well, I will try @John Joe

Comment: Is it true that the query looks like this:
"SELECT * FROM " + Constant.TableName + " WHERE "+ Constant.id_postFav +"="+ id_post;

Comment: yes, or this `"SELECT "+ Constant.id_postFav+" FROM " + Constant.TableName + " WHERE "+ Constant.id_postFav +"="+ id_post;`

Comment: there is a little problem here, i take id_post (from JSON) by defining it as String. when I change the constructor its String type, this method does not work. Do I have to define id_post (from JSON) as Integer? @John Joe

Comment: I not familiar with JSON. Would it be a problem if you change from `String` to `int` ?

Comment: nothing seems to matter. I've changed it, in what constructor fieldValue field will I fill?

Comment: you need to pass id_post  to checkDuplicate() method

Comment: Ok. I have filled it with favorites.getId_PostFav, but it's Integer type. Due to accommodate the Constant.Id_PostFav field defined in SQLite as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. I have tried experimenting with changing the constructor method ie fieldValue that type of Integer in accordance with the actual value .. but this has not succeeded @John Joe

Comment: what not success? What exception you get ?

Comment: this method fails to check.. @John Joe

Comment: this method has not been successful in checking. there is still a gap for the same data entered @John Joe

Comment: @JohnJoe Amazing answer. You probably save me time for messing around in the internet.

Comment: @4xMafole glad  it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Crate a function to check row is in db or not

```
private static boolean CheckIsInDBorNot(String titleFav) {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Constant.favoritDBtable + " WHERE " + Constant.titleFav +"'"+titleFav "'";
        final SQLiteDatabase db = open();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    }
```

than check

```
if (!CheckIsInDBorNot(commentOrderId, commentId)) {
                db.insertOrThrow(Constant.favoritDBtable, null, cVal);
            }
```

It will check and insert

Comment: what is the purpose of open() function is this.getReadableDB() ?

Comment: it returns writable sqlitedatbase

Answer (score 0):

Create method `IsItemExist()` in your `DatabaseHelper` class and call this method in you activity class like `IsItemExist(name,mobile)`

```
 public boolean IsItemExist(String name,String mobile) {
    try
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+NAME+" FROM "+TABLE+" WHERE "+NAME+"=?",new String[]{name});
        Cursor cursor1=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+MOBILE+" FROM "+TABLE+" WHERE "+MOBILE+"=?",new String[]{mobile});
        if (cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor1.moveToFirst())
        {
            db.close();
            Log.d("Record  Already Exists", "Table is:"+TABLE+" ColumnName:"+NAME);
            return true;//record Exists

        }
        Log.d("New Record  ", "Table is:"+TABLE+" ColumnName:"+NAME+" Column Value:"+NAME);
        db.close();
    }
    catch(Exception errorException)
    {
        Log.d("Exception occured", "Exception occured "+errorException);
        // db.close();
    }

        return false;

}
```

Comment: Please write a few words explaining your answer and how your approach works.

Comment: Create method IsItemExist() in your DatabaseHelper class and call this method in you activity class like databaseHelper.IsItemExist(name,mobile)